# Angular, Drag and Drop, change text while dragging element

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop

How to change text of draggable element, while dragging, I have snippet from cdk/drag-and-drop library. It gives parameter to catch event while, dragging. I can change via native element, but it changes all styles, and also I need to set another event on dragover or other actions. What are the options, If I want put random text on dragging element?

In Html

```
(cdkDragStarted)="dragStarted($event)"
```

In TS

```
dragStarted(event) {  
    event.source.element.nativeElement.textContent = '1212';
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put random text on dragging element, you should use [*cdkDragPreview](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview#customizing-the-drag-preview)

Comment: Thank you very much, you made my day! I know how to do in Vanila JS, but not with this module.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but I know [renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) is the recommended way to deal with template interaction from the ts file. Perhaps in the drag method try modifying the text using renderer2. If it's not changing correctly still, my next step would be doing some manual change detection in the dragStarted method.
If you want it temporarily changed while being dragged, muravev's response has you covered.

Comment: In my case, I need to make some calculation during dragging element, in your case, I would need to modify text back again on drop, I think it would be more complicated rather than use existing directive.